# how to read xml file from url in tibco BW

Tags: tibco

I want to read xml file from web url, when I specified that path in Read file pallette file location I'm getting an error .How can I do this one in tibco?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: please specify the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a "Send HTTP Request" Activity.

Host in the "Configuration" tab can be written as such : hostname:port/dir1/dir2/filename.xml

Data will be available in the "asciiContent" output field.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use "HTTP receiver" Activity
2.Next use "Parse XML" Activity